# split json object to post many column in database

Tags: php, database, api, rest, frameworks

I have a web server that serves request rest api to post in to my database...
so i need to split rest api json object and post to many columns

rest api requet post like this.....

```
{"name":"keyboard,23,12"}
```

i want to post into database like this...

```
 table name : products

    -------------------------------------------------
    | product_name    |  product_price | product_qty|
    -------------------------------------------------
    | keyboard        | 23             | 12         |
    |                 |                |            |
    |                 |                |            |    
    |                 |                |            |
```

and my web server php code....

**addProduct.php**

```
    <?php

require_once('includes/initialize.php');

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

$response = array();

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    
    $result = $api->addProduct($name, $name, $name);
    
    if($result){
        $response['status'] = "00";
        $response['message'] = "Product inserted successfully";
    }else{
        $response['status'] = "06";
        $response['message'] = "Error inserting product";
    }   
    echo json_encode($response);
    }else{
        $response['status'] = "99";
        $response['message'] = "Required parameters missing";
    
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

**initialize.php**

```
<?php
    
    require_once('config.php');
    require_once('models/Database.php');
    require_once('models/Api.php');

?>
```

**Api.php**

```
<?php
    class Api{
        
        private $db;
        
        public function __construct(){
            $this->db = new Database;
        }
        
        public function findBySql($query){
            $this->db->query($query);
            
            $set = $this->db->resultSet();
            
            return $set;
        }
        public function addProduct($prdt_name, $prdt_price, $prdt_qty){
            $this->db->query('INSERT INTO products(product_name, product_price, Product_qty) VALUES (:name, :name, :name)');
            $this->db->bind(':name', $prdt_name);
            $this->db->bind(':name', $prdt_price);
            $this->db->bind(':name', $prdt_qty);
            
            
            if($this->db->execute()){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
                
        }
        
    }
    
    $api = new Api()
?>
```

**Database.php**

```
<?php

class Database{
private $host = DB_SERVER;
private $user = DB_USERNAME;
private $pass = DB_PASSWORD;
private $dbname = DB_NAME;

private $dbh;
private $stmt;
private $error;

public function __construct(){
//set DSN
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
//$dsn = 'mysql:host==' . $this->host . ';port=8012' . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;

$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    
    
    //create PDO Instance
    try{
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        echo $this->error;
    }
    
    }
    
    //prepare statement with query
    
    public function query($sql){
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    }
    
    //bind values
    
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
    
    if(is_null($type)){
        switch(true){
        case is_int($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
        break;
        case is_bool ($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        break;
        case is_null($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
        break;
        default:
            $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
        
        }
        
        //execute the prepared statement
        
        public function execute(){
            return $this->stmt->execute();
        }
        
        
        //get result set as array of objects
        
        public function resultSet(){
            $this->execute();
            return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }

        //get single record as objects
        
        public function single(){
            $this->execute();
            return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
            
            
        }
        
        ?>
```

please revise the code above, because I have tried many ways but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the whole code. But the way you have defined the payload, it looks conceptually wrong in the first place. You are dumping name, price & quantity in a single JSON field called "name". It is maintainece nightmare. If s new developer looks into the api code without any context he or she won't be able to understand anything from it. It lacks clarity. You should define three different fields for each of the values. And modify your code accordingly. It would be clearer & easy to code. That would be my suggestion.

Comment: I know, but in certain cases, I only have the option of a single json, that's why I need your help ..

i know an explode function but i don't know how to implement into this code ....

please you guys can help me, thank you